# MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, connection

My ISP (1&1) informs me that the maximum number of MySQL connections I can have open at any one time is 18. My LAMP stack application uses SQL for almost every page but I close each connection after use. I know each connection will only be open for a few ms and that there are many variables here, but does anyone have a feel for how many users 18 connections will cater for? I want to preempt problems down the line when my number of users increases.

Comment: [Do you know about dba.stackexchange site? If you are not getting a satisfied answer you can migrate the post there (no cross post)](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) =)

Answer (score 1):

This seems bizarre. I understand that there are Internet Service Providers (ISPs) that throttle connections, but 18 seems arbitrarily low. The real performance hit MySQL is not the number of connections but the volume & complexity of the queries.

So first recommendation would be to genuinely find another ISP.  Barring that I would recommend disabling persistent connections on your MySQL queries. But still that seems like it would run against the 18 limit if/when a rush of activity happens. Genuinely, find another ISP or ask your current one to validly explain how anyone can work with such a limit.